# Can use dataframe ix for assignment, but not retrieval

Tags: python, pandas

I am looping through rows of a pandas df, loop index i.
I am able to assign several columns using the ix function with the loop index as first parameter, column name as second.
However, when I try to retrieve/print using this method,

```
print(df.ix[i,"Run"])
```

I get a the following Typerror: str object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
somehow related to Keyerror: 'Run'

Not quite sure why this is occurring, as Run is indeed a column in the dataframe.
Any suggestions?

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py\!", line 3124, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
  File \!"pandas\_libs\index.pyx\!", line 55, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box
  File \!"pandas\_libs\index.pyx\!", line 63, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \!"C:\...", line 365, in <module>
    print(df.ix[i,\!"Run\!"])
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py\!", line 116, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py\!", line 870, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py\!", line 1027, in _getitem_lowerdim
    return getattr(section, self.name)[new_key]
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py\!", line 122, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py\!", line 1116, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py\!", line 136, in _get_label
    return self.obj[label]
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py\!", line 767, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py\!", line 3132, in get_value
    raise e1
  File \!"C:\WPy-3670\python-3.6.7.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py\!", line 3118, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File \!"pandas\_libs\index.pyx\!", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File \!"pandas\_libs\index.pyx\!", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File \!"pandas\_libs\index.pyx\!", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File \!"pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi\!", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File \!"pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi\!", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Run'
"
```

Upon changing the name of the column I print to any other column, it does work correctly.  Earlier in the code, I "compressed" the rows, which had multiple rows per unique string in 'Run' column, using the following.

```
df=df.groupby('Run').max()
```

Did this last line somehow remove the column/column name from the table?

Comment: Yes. The column `Run` is gone and the unique values of that column are now your index.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there is a way to keep the Run column afterwards?  When I print the data to csv still remains (I guess as the index, which isn't clear from csv).

Answer (score 3):

`ix` has been [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html). `ix` has always been ambiguous: does `ix[10]` refer to the row with the label 10, or the row at position 10?

Use `loc` or `iloc` instead:

```
df.loc[i,"Run"] = ... # by label

df.iloc[i]["Run"] = ... # by position
```

As for the `groupby` removing `Run`: it moves `Run` to the index of the data frame. To get it back as a column, call `reset_index`:

```
df=df.groupby('Run').max().reset_index()
```

---

#### Differences between indexing by label and position:

Suppose you have a series like this:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], index=np.arange(0,9,2))

0    a
2    b
4    c
6    d
8    e
```

The first column is the labels (aka the index). The second column is the values of the series.

Label based indexing:

```
s.loc[2] --> b
s.loc[3] --> error. The label doesn't exist
```

Position based indexing:

```
s.iloc[2] --> c. since `a` has position 0, `b` has position 1, and so on
s.iloc[3] --> d
```

According to the documentation, `s.ix[3]` would have returned `d` since it first searches for the label `3`. When that fails, it falls back to the position 3. On my machine (Pandas 0.24.2), it returns an error, along with a deprecation warning, so I guess the developers changed it to behave like `loc`.

If you want to use mixed indexing, you have to be explicit about that:

```
s.loc[3] if 3 in s.index else s.iloc[3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't quite sure about how to translate these properly, I still wanted to use "mixed" indices.  In your statement though, what exactly is the difference between by label, or by position, if they are both returning a value by label and position?

Comment: Although this is good information, it doesn't answer the original question which was whether the column name was removed in a group by.

Comment: Thank you for the details.  However, I went back in my code and replaced every call to df.ix[i,"col name"] with df.iloc[i]["col name"] and the result was a blank dataframe, or rather, the blank dataframe I had originally initialized.  Why can I not simply replace df.ix[i,"col name"] with df.iloc[i]["col name"]?